# How to wait for a Future who hasn't been submitted to a thread pool yet?

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrent.futures

I would like to create a "TaskPoolManager" who start "Task" (custom object) in a `ThreadPoolExecutor` and prioritize them with importance level, time since submit, etc. (Those are properties of Task)

My problem is when the `ThreadPoolExecutor` is full, the other task submits to the pool will be executed in "FIFO" and not prioritize.

Here the `TaskPoolManager` class:

```py
class TaskPoolManager:
    def __init__(self, max_workers: int = None):
        self.max_workers = max_workers or (os.cpu_count() or 1) * 5
        self._pool_executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=self.max_workers, 
                                                 thread_name_prefix="TaskPoolManager")
        self.pending_task: Dict[Task, Future] = {Task(func=None): Future()}
        self.running_workers = 0

    # Task are callable
    def submit(self, task: Task) -> Future:
        if self.running_workers == self.max_workers:
            return self._add_task_to_queue(task)
        else:
            return self._start_task(task)

    def _start_task(self, task: Task) -> Future:
        """Submit a task in the pool"""
        self.running_workers = self.running_workers + 1
        future = self._pool_executor.submit(task)
        future.add_done_callback(lambda x: self._completed_thread())
        return future

    def _add_task_to_queue(self, task: Task) -> Future:
        """Add task to the not started task queue"""
        not_started_future = Future()
        self.pending_task[task] = not_started_future
        return not_started_future

    def _completed_thread(self):
        """Call when a thread in the pool as terminated a task"""
        self.running_workers = self.running_workers - 1
        self._start_task_in_queue()  # By priority level
```

Here an example of how to use it:

```py
manager = TaskPoolManager()

for i in range(0, 10000):
    manager.submit(Task(func=wait_random_time_task))

f = manager.submit(Task(func=wait_random_time_task))

# This isn't submitted to the thread pool yet, but need to be waitable like it is.
f.result()
```

Is there a way to connect a client instantiated `Future` to a `Future` instance created by `ThreadPoolExecutor.submit` later in the execution?

If not, is there a way to return a `Future` like object who can be associated with a future later and still wait for `.result()`?

In other words: How to wait for a Future who hasn't been submitted to a thread pool yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, it wasn't that complicated:

```py
def _start_task_in_queue(self):
    try:
        # Algorithm could be more complex than just the first one
        task, returned_future = next(iter(self.pending_task.items()))
    except StopIteration:
        return
    started_future = self._pool_executor.submit(task)
    started_future.add_done_callback(lambda result: returned_future.set_result(result))
```

I don't know if it's the best way to solve my problem, cause `Future.__init__` specify that:

> Initializes the future. Should not be called by clients

But it works that way.